# python wx changing windows size

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wx gui application.

the user can change the window size with the mouse (same as any other window)
the problem is that my window isn't auto adjust to the new size of the window.

How do I do that?

iv'e looked it up but all guides are for tkinter which is not relevant for my project at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set everything up correctly with [sizers](http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers) the window should resize automatically to the correct size. You should have assigned the window to some sizer with `self.SetSizer(window)`. If you have this and it doesn't work, you may need to use something like `SetSizerAndFit` instead.

Alternatively, you may need to write explicit code to adjust features of your window bound to an `EVT_SIZE` event.

With no code in your question or any further details it's difficult to help more...